# How to add margin between elements in side container without pushing to next row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 3 items which are wrapped inside a container. I have added back ground color and padding to them.

Now When I want add some margin between them , it is shifting to next row.

```
.div-category{
  background-color: #2274A5;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  color: whitesmoke;
  //margin-right: 10px; Shifts line to next row.
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/67500/)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaina');

/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #231123;
  background-color: #F4E04D;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}



.div-category{
  background-color: #2274A5;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <div class="container marketing">
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text1</h2>
            <p>Paragraph1 </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4 div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text2</h2>
            <p>Paragraph2.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4 div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text3</h2>
            <p>Paragraph3</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
```

Comment: you want 3 divs in same row?

Comment: Yes @charankumar, Need them in same row after adding margin

Comment: @Simsons do you want margin in right or bottom??

Comment: I want the margin to the right..

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) (Bootstrap built-in spacing) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860143/bootstrap-add-margin-to-column) (adding margin to a column in Bootstrap)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your structure a bit, here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0g2a3kt7/)

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="div-category">
        ---
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="div-category">
        ---
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="div-category">
        ---
    </div>
</div>
```

and little margin like

```
.col-lg-4 .div-category{
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

it should work

```css
@import url('http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #231123;
  background-color: #F4E04D;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}



.div-category{
  background-color: #2274A5;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.col-lg-4 .div-category{
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="container marketing">
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text1</h2>
            <p>Paragraph1 </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text2</h2>
            <p>Paragraph2.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="div-category">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Text3</h2>
            <p>Paragraph3</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

then add one more div inside and apply margin to that .inside-margin class

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 div-category">
<div class="inside-margin">

</div>
</div>

.inside-margin{ margin:0 5px; }
```

Comment: That still shifts it to next row. Please have a look at the jsFiddle or snipper.

Comment: you are viewing in medium device, you need to add extra col-md-4 and col-sm-4 along with col-lg-4, i have edited my code

Answer (score -1):

it is because you have utilised 12 columns of grid and then you are trying to apply margin and because entire space of screen has been utilised by 12 columns it lacks space and wraps to new row.

you can change **col-lg-4** to **col-lg-3** and then try to give margin.

Comment: Thats not the solution . It will squeeze the container too narrow.

Comment: @Simsons you can do one thing. wrap the content of each block in another div and apply padding to that div. it will add space between each block items. and also apply background color to that div only

Comment: @Simsons have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/to5pzqLg/
and let me know if it serves your purpose.